# Using pgfplots, tikzpicture tick labels have inconsistent spacing in float environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, floats

I have a double-spaced document I'm trying to put a graph into. I created the graph and everything worked great, until I tried to put the figure [H].

MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\doublespacing

Figure~\ref{fig:good} shows how I want this to look. Figure~\ref{fig:bad} messes up the tick labels.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,
    axis on top,
    axis equal image,
    xlabel = {X Info},
    ylabel = {Y Info},
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 5,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 5,
    grid=both,
    tick label style={major tick length=0pt},
    xtick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    xticklabels={1\\\small{Label}, 2\\\small{Label}, 3\\\small{Label}, 4\\\small{Label}, 5\\\small{Label}},
    xticklabel style={anchor=north east, align=center},
    x label style={yshift=-1em},
    ytick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    yticklabels={1\\\small{Label}, 2\\\small{Label}, 3\\\small{Label}, 4\\\small{Label}, 5\\\small{Label}},
    yticklabel style={anchor=north east, align=center},
    y label style={yshift=1em},
    ]
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Good Figure} \label{fig:good}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,
    axis on top,
    axis equal image,
    xlabel = {X Info},
    ylabel = {Y Info},
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 5,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 5,
    grid=both,
    tick label style={major tick length=0pt},
    xtick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    xticklabels={1\\\small{Label}, 2\\\small{Label}, 3\\\small{Label}, 4\\\small{Label}, 5\\\small{Label}},
    xticklabel style={anchor=north east, align=center},
    x label style={yshift=-1em},
    ytick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    yticklabels={1\\\small{Label}, 2\\\small{Label}, 3\\\small{Label}, 4\\\small{Label}, 5\\\small{Label}},
    yticklabel style={anchor=north east, align=center},
    y label style={yshift=1em},
    ]
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Bad Figure} \label{fig:bad}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How do I get the label line spacing from the first figure into the second figure using the [H] placement? The only difference between the two figures is [h] vs [H].

[image: MWE for bad tick labels]

Comment: font commands like `\small` are switches not macros. They don't take arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setspace` is locally setting the baseline back to normal in "real" floats but not in `H` adding `\singlespacing` gives the same layout.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\doublespacing

Figure~\ref{fig:good} shows how I want this to look. Figure~\ref{fig:bad} messes up the tick labels.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering

%\showthe\baselineskip
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,
    axis on top,
    axis equal image,
    xlabel = {X Info},
    ylabel = {Y Info},
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 5,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 5,
    grid=both,
    tick label style={major tick length=0pt},
    xtick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    xticklabels={1\\\small{Label}, 2\\\small{Label}, 3\\\small{Label}, 4\\\small{Label}, 5\\\small{Label}},
    xticklabel style={anchor=north east, align=center},
    x label style={yshift=-1em},
    ytick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    yticklabels={1\\\small{Label}, 2\\\small{Label}, 3\\\small{Label}, 4\\\small{Label}, 5\\\small{Label}},
    yticklabel style={anchor=north east, align=center},
    y label style={yshift=1em},
    ]
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Good Figure} \label{fig:good}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]\singlespacing
    \centering

%\showthe\baselineskip
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,
    axis on top,
    axis equal image,
    xlabel = {X Info},
    ylabel = {Y Info},
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 5,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 5,
    grid=both,
    tick label style={major tick length=0pt},
    xtick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    xticklabels={1\\\small{Label}, 2\\\small{Label}, 3\\\small{Label}, 4\\\small{Label}, 5\\\small{Label}},
    xticklabel style={anchor=north east, align=center},
    x label style={yshift=-1em},
    ytick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    yticklabels={1\\\small{Label}, 2\\\small{Label}, 3\\\small{Label}, 4\\\small{Label}, 5\\\small{Label}},
    yticklabel style={anchor=north east, align=center},
    y label style={yshift=1em},
    ]
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Bad Figure} \label{fig:bad}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

unrelated but the syntax is `{\small Label}` not `\small{Label}` although I left it in the above.